# This doesn't work, not sure why... SpigotMC

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

Why isnt the EntityZombieHusk working here? I'm using 1.16.5 jar file for this
`package com.TheRealBee.mob;`

`public class CustomPet extends EntityZombieHusk{}`

Any help is appreciated
 My IDE has a function that makes it so that if the class is not imported it would give you suggestions on what to import but none showed up

 Error type: Cannot resolve symbol "EntityZombieHusk"

Edit: I forgot to import the spigot-1.16.5.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE returns an error because it doesn't know where the `EntityZombieHusk` class is.  That class in not present in the Bukkit/Spigot API, which means you have to import `NMS` (`net.minecraft.server`) to use it.

---

To import NMS:

**Maven**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**:

```
compileOnly "org.spigotmc:spigot:version"
```

---

**Note**: Make sure to change the version; otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Oh no I didn't learn this, may I have a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: What are you using to compile and package (jar) your plugin?  Maven?  Gradle?  IntelliJ?  Eclipse?

Comment: IntelliJ,

ill need to type for the minimum character limit so